# function fixed element when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fixed

```
function elementFixed(el) {
    var howScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
    var cOff = $('.main-content').offset();
    var fOff = $('.site-footer').offset();
    var elH = el.outerHeight();
    var elTop = parseInt(el.css('top'));

    $(el).css('top', 0)

    if (howScroll >= cOff.top) {

        $('el').css({
            'top': (howScroll - cOff.top) + 'px',
            'position': 'relative',
            'top': 0
        });
        var elTop = parseInt(el.css('top'));
        if ((elTop) >= (fOff.top - elH)) {
            $(el).css('top', fOff.top - (cOff.top + elH + 50));
        }
    }
```

Hello, I would like to use the transcribed top pages of my project .
The function allows you to scroll a particular item while you scroll the entire page .
I do not know if I wrote the function correctly , but I would pass as a parameter to the class of the element that should scroll with the scroll of the page

I await suggestions

Comment: You could use fixed positioned element instead.

Comment: I partly solved , but another problem arose , the function is not part of firefox and ie